# JAX-WS 2.0 - Migrating from xsd:double to xsd:decimal

Tags: java, web-services, floating-point, jax-ws

I've written an application that relies heavily on data obtained from web services for which I have generated JAX-WS clients. The WSDL uses xsd:double types to represent all floating point types, but as they sometimes represent monetary amounts I would like to change them all to xsd:decimal objects. As long as I am using my own copy of the WSDL with all xsd:double occurrences changed to xsd:decimal, and stubs generated from the modified WSDL, am I likely to encounter any issues?

Thanks and kind regards,

Joseph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're not dependent on being able to encode any "weird values" / IEEE-754 niceties (depending on your viewpoint) like -0.0, infinity, or NaN, and are careful to avoid an impedance mismatch between what the web services provide and what your application expects, I don't believe that you should encounter any issues.

I assume that these values will be handled as `BigDecimal`s in your application?

Comment: `BigDecimal`s will handle the xsd:decimal objects. I don't expect to get any `NaN`s or `Infinity`s coming back but that could be an issue if they do.

Comment: @Joseph: then you should be fine.

Comment: I believe that you may have issues if the service encodes the double value using scientific notation.  xsd:decimal specifically prohibits scientific notation, whereas xsd:double allows it as an option.

Comment: Yes I thought about that... Hopefully it won't happen as the monetary values are small. Time will tell!